# AVAudioRecorder not updating peakPowerForChannel

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

For my cocos 2d game I want to detect voice from iPhone's mic and it should play automatically for this I am using peakPowerForChannel of AVAudioRecorder.
Code:

```
const double ALPHA = 0.05;
NSString *currentRecorder = @"nil";
NSError *error;
if (checker.recording) {
    [checker updateMeters];
    currentRecorder = @"checker";
    peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (ALPHA* [checker peakPowerForChannel:0]));
}
else if (recorder.recording) {
    [recorder updateMeters];
    peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (ALPHA * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    currentRecorder = @"recorder";
}
// NSLog(@"-------------- %f",lowPassResults);
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  
NSLog(@"%@ >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> %f   peakPowerForChannel ---%f",currentRecorder,lowPassResults,peakPowerForChannel);
if (lowPassResults > 0.4) {
    if (!recorder.recording) {
        [checker stop];
    }
    else {
        if (recorder.recording) {
            [recorder stop];
            [checker record];
        }
    }
```

It works fine for first time, but after playing an audio the `[recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]` gives a constant value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[recorder updateMeters]` updates the value once only. Every time you check for `[recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]` value. You must call `[recorder updateMeters]` method.
So good way is to check for the value in a timer and call `[recorder updateMeters]` method before checking the value.

Comment: what is checker and recorder in the code? Are they 2 different recorders?

Comment: M not able to understand this Code.. What u wanna do in this? 

   if (lowPassResults >0.4){
        if (!recorder.recording) {
            [checker stop];
}
    else{
        if (recorder.recording) {
            [recorder stop];
 [checker record];

        }
M not sure that recorder is on 2nd time. 
initialize intial value of peakPowerForChannel = 0; Then check for logs

Comment: I got the reason for not updating the value. This happens because I played an audio effect using simple audio engin(in cocos2d ). I changed it with avaudioplayer it works fine now

Comment: gr8.. :) .. I wonder why you are not using CDAudioManager in cocos...
I have created 3 apps based on Voice Recording in cocos.. I used CDAudioManager for all of those... I don't know what functionality you want to implement.. 
[link]http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kooka/id401134800?mt=8

Comment: I Used CDAudioManager for playing the sound.. AVAudioRecorder was used for recording.

Comment: nice app,I like it. My need is to implement the auto listening and speaking it with change in sound tone(pitch change) after listening. Can you say how to implement it.

Comment: means u exactly want 2 implement what I implemented... :P 
What you did is right.  I checked your code.. Main thing you need to change is just 1 recorder. And play via CDAudioManger. Actually whats d problem with AVAudio Player is that It saves your sound and den plays it. So after some time you have memory problem and your app crashes. So to avoid this use CDAudioManager as it uses same slot for storing. So 1 time only 1 sound is stored that you play. I'll tell you the functionality. Add me offline on aneja.nikhil@gmail.com ..